# Use object returned from helper in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am trying to use a object property returned from a helper in handlebars

```js
handlebars.registerHelper("calcPercentage", (newVal, oldVal) => {
  const computed = round((newVal - oldVal) / oldVal, 1);

  return {
    computed,
    className: computed.toString().startsWith("-") ? "red" : "green"
  };
});
```

```html
<p>{{calcPercentage this.totalOrders this.totalPreviousOrders}}</p>
```

Here I'd like to use the computed property, how can I achieve this?

Comment: have you got the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using

```html
<p style="display: inline-block; padding-bottom: 0;">
  {{#with (calcPercentage this.totalOrders this.totalPreviousOrders)}}
    {{computed}}
  {{/with}}%
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below, This one is working.

```
var data = {
  yes: "Great Final got it"
};

hbs.handlebars.registerHelper("count", function(price) {
  return data[price];
});
```

Hbs look like below,

```
<p>
  {{count 'yes'}}
</p>
```

Check the demo link below [ClickHere](https://codesandbox.io/embed/funny-chaum-7e907?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: This could also be a solution, I found a way to use the value directly